# Arc Length in polar coordinates for $r=\theta$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, arc-length

To find the arclength of the spiral above from $0$ to $2\pi$, we use

$$s=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\theta^2+1}d\theta$$

After doing and initial trig substitution of $\theta=\tan{x}$ and the I.B.P., we get that

$$2\int_C \sec^3{x}dx=(\sec x \tan x+x)|_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}$$

Back substituting and dividing by 2 gives

$$\int_C \sec^3{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\theta\sqrt{\theta^2+1}+\arctan{\theta}\right]_0^{2\pi}=\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan{2\pi}\approx 20.69412...$$

However, if I let Wolfram Alpha solve this it gives

$$s=\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1}+\frac{1}{2}\sinh^{-1}{2\pi}\approx 21.2563...$$

What gives??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$\displaystyle \int \sec^3 x ~ \mathrm dx \ne \sec x \tan x + x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sec%5E3+x+dx)

Comment: I see what I did...I had $$\int_C{\sec{x}(\tan^2{x}}dx=\int_C{\sec{x}(\sec^2{x}-1)}dx$$ and I never sent the $\sec{x}$ to $1$.